# Count the total number of ASCII code in a column for each row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table with a lot of ASCII code scattered through it. I'm using the REPLACE operator to remove it but before I remove it I need to find the total of each different piece of ASCII code.
My current code is almost working correctly but I run into an issue when ASCII code is right next to each other.... eg. "48%  of the registered voters,  NOT  48% of citizens ==&gt;&gt;  BIG ! HUGE  DIFFERENCE."....My code below is only counting the ASCII code once not twice. Any help to get around this issue would be appreciated. If you need any more info please ask.

```
SELECT comments, COUNT(*) AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%&amp;gt;%' 
GROUP BY comments
```

Comment: amp should be before the gt; and after the & in the example. Not sure why amp isn't showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of times that a string appears:

```
SELECT comments, 
       (length(replace(comments, '&amp;gt;' , 'X&amp;gt;')) - length(comments)) as NumOccurrences
FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%&amp;gt;%' ;
```

I'm not sure that `'&amp;gt;'` is the string you really want to search for.  But the idea is pretty simple.  Replace the string with a string one character longer and then use `length()` to count the frequency within the comment.

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL . . . That was because of the `'%'` left on the end of the first replacement string.